# Angular2: Make a child routing path equals to the Root routing path is a good solution?

Tags: angular, routes

To make my question clear, let me use some images.
This is my project structure:

[image]

Thinking about code reuse, I wrote one component like this:

[image]

And at my app.module.ts, I wrote the routings like this:

[image]

Because the Landing Page of my application is also the root of the free-area, I wrote its routing path like the root routing path, which means, I set it as blank.

The routing is working fine, but is this a good practice? How could I set up the path of the Landing Page if it is not a good practice?

Comment: please, avoid posting your code as images it is a real pain to read or to reuse it for an answer.

Comment: Ok, I will do it next time. Thank you for the consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok. you need to add

```
{path: '**', redirect:'', pathMatch:'full'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, but wouldn't it be "redirectTo", instead of "redirect" ?

Comment: both are valid.

Comment: It throws me the error "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'redirect' does not exist in type 'Route'.". Anyway, I will give a vote for your answer because you made a good contribution. If there aren't any other answer, I will accept this one. Thank you so much.